# netsurf package for buildroot?

Tags: raspberry-pi, buildroot

I'm looking for a small footprint lightweight browser to run on a Raspi. I've come across netsurf which I find especially appealing due to it's fb version - it would allow me to drop X11 completely and have much faster startup times until my (web based) GUI shows.

Unfortunaltely, I cannot see any netsurf support for buildroot... There is a netsurf-buildsystem package, but I cannot figure what this is for.

Do any of you know if a netsurf package for buildroot is planned?

cheers, Wolfgang

Answer (score 0):

netsurf-buildsystem is a host package that is needed by libsvgtiny (the svg rendering library from netsurf). Like most open source projects, we don't define detailed plans for what packages / features should be added in the future, instead future changes are defined by whatever patches people submit.

Netsurf looks interesting, but so far nobody has worked on including it.

So in other words, the way to get netsurf support in Buildroot is to submit a patch.